# wso2 property to endpoint's address

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

What i am trying to do is get the value of property and put it in my endpoint's uri

my property

```
<property value="1" name="id" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
```

my endpoint's address

```
<address format="rest" uri="http://localhost:port/service?id={id}"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this using a http endpoint,

```
     <property name="uri.var.id" value="1" type="STRING"/>
     <send>
        <endpoint>
           <http uri-template="http://localhost:port/service?id={uri.var.id}"/>
        </endpoint>
     </send>
```

Answer (score 2):

There might be different solutions but one trick is to set the 'To' header with the value of the uri and then just call the send mediator. Like so:

```
<header name="To" expression="fn:concat('http://localhost:port/service?id=', get-property('id'))"/>
<send/>
```